# Android Spring RestTemplate with Proxy

Tags: android, spring, proxy, spring-android

i need to read the proxy information from the phone and if the phone  is under a proxy i need to set this proxy on my spring restTemplate object.I've tried the follow code without any luck, could anyone tell me what i'm doing  wrong.

```
String proxyHost = android.net.Proxy.getHost(activity
            .getApplicationContext());

SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, 8080));
requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the answer for my question .. will post here the code:

```
 if (proxyHost != null && proxyPort != null) {
        rest = new RestTemplate();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory =   ((HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) rest
                .getRequestFactory());
        DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = (DefaultHttpClient) factory
                .getHttpClient();
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);
        defaultHttpClient.getParams().setParameter(
                ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);

    } else {
        rest = new RestTemplate();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = ((HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) rest
                .getRequestFactory());
        DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = (DefaultHttpClient) factory
                .getHttpClient();

    }
```

Comment: `defaultHttpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);`! Thank you, you just made my day! I was trying to combine a connection to a service that requires HTTP basic authentication with the requirement to use a proxy, and this finally allows me to do it.